# Marketing Cloud data & configuration backup

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, backup

Does anyone know if and how it is possible to take a backup of the whole production org (Marketing Cloud/Exacttarget) before any go live activity?

We are implementing the MCC and would like to ensure that if something goes wrong, we have a backup to restore the production org data if required.

Comment: backup means how you need to backup the  data?

Answer (score 4):

There multiple ways to 'backup' in Marketing Cloud. 
There is not a simple function per-se, but for data extensions and All Subscribers, you could perform a Data Extract and extract all records to FTP etc.

For backing up data extension schema's and backing up emails, again, nothing really out of box, but we have built a custom backup 'app' which uses the SFMC API to retrieve/copy the schemas and emails.

If you are implementing MCC and Sycronised Data Extensions, then your risk is low.

It shouldn't affect your Emails, or other data extensions - but every deployment is different.

The risk to watch out for is mainly your Contact Model, if you bring in the incorrect Contacts (e.g. connectng to incorrect SF environment)  then you will end up messing up / duplicating your contacts in SFMC

Answer (score 0):

I know this is very old but want to leave a note for anyone looking.

Take a look at stashr.io for SFMC backup and recovery.